# What do I roll to throw a heavy, iron door at someone?

Tags: dnd-5e, weight, throwing-things

If I were to throw a 30-40 pound iron door at someone, what dice would I roll, and what modifiers would apply? Would someone be at disadvantage? Let's say that I have 20 strength, 13 dexterity, and there's someone about 30 feet away. What's the DC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Up to the DM

I assume you are trying to do that as an attack. Although the books have rules on Improvised Weapons that could apply here, due to the weight of the mentioned object (and the not-exactly-comfortable-to-hold-and-throw shape), the DM could require an Athletics Check just to see if you are able to do that, to *then* resolve the attack as an Improvised Weapon.

For thrown improvised weapons, we have

> An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.

So, by throwing it at 30 ft away, **you do have disadvantage since you are throwing it farther than the normal range**. Since it's an improvised weapon, you don't have proficiency with it, thus the Attack Roll modifier is just +5 (your Str modifier), and the damage is 1d4 + 5 (1d4 + STR). The DM could obviously rule the damage differently.

About the DC, it is again up to the DM. While certainly with a score of 20 in Str you can lift or carry the door, throwing it might prove harder. Still, 30-40 pounds is not *that* much, especially for some adventurer used to, you know, axing dragons. My personal guess would be a DC of 15 to 20, but again, that's completely up to the DM and YMMV from table to table.

Comment: The shot-put world record is 23m (roughly 60 feet) with a 16 pound ball. It might be possible to throw a 40-pound object (which has a suboptimal shape for flight) 30 feet, but I'd definitely give it a 25+ DC, unless the character is a professional shot-put-champion or otherwise has a lot of experience throwing heavy objects.

Comment: @PixelMaster My adjudication is that "can I throw it?" is independent from the distance, which is then considered in the Disadvantage in the attack roll. Additionally, the DC reflects the difficulty of the task, and should **not** change according to the character being a professional something or having experience - that is included in his proficiency bonus and his Str bonus.

Comment: Note that, RAW, *any* character can throw a pike, which weights 18 lb, up to 60 ft with disadvantage, or up to 20 ft without disadvantage at all.

Comment: fair enough. I suppose you could instead allow a professional to add his proficiency bonus to the check, or give him expertise for this one check. Either way, I think 15 is a too low DC in this case.